# Functions such that $f(\frac{x+y}{2})=\frac{1}{2}f(x)+\frac{1}{2}f(y).$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

What are the continuous functions $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that for every $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$

$$f(\frac{x+y}{2})=\frac{1}{2}f(x)+\frac{1}{2}f(y).$$

Comment: does it have to be continuous?

Comment: Not possible if continuous... let the Banach space be $R$ for example. The variable $t$ is extraneous in the context of this question as well.

Comment: Every affine non-linear function does the job.

Comment: @nayrb So if we add the continuity condition, does this mean $f$ must be affine ? I will reformulate the question to look better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$
\begin{align}
a &= {f(y)-f(x)\over y-x}\\
b &= f(x) - ax\\
g(x) &= ax + b
\end{align}
$$

Clearly $g(x) = f(x)$.  A bit of math shows also that $g(y) = f(y)$.

Given that 
$$
f\left({x+y\over 2}\right)=\frac{1}{2}f(x)+\frac{1}{2}f(y)
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
g\left({x+y\over 2}\right) &= a\left({x+y\over 2}\right) + b\\
&= {ax + b\over 2} + {ay+b\over 2}\\
&= {1\over 2} f(x) + {1\over 2}f(y)\\
&= f\left({x+y\over 2}\right)
\end{align}
$$

If we define $\delta = y-x$, we can extend this for any rational number $r = p/{2^N}$ where $p,N$ are integers:

$$
f(x+p\delta) = g(x+p\delta) = a(x+p\delta) + b
$$

Thus, if $f(x)$ is continuous, it must be linear.